# How can I edit /proc/net/tcp?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp, proc, tcp-ip

I need to edit 1 line in `/proc/net/tcp` while the file is also used by the linux kernel for updating other lines of it by the kernel.

**Background:** Each line in `/proc/net/tcp` represents a TCP socket. The kernel uses this file to show the state and statistics of each socket in the system. I want to fake the statisics of 1 socket in the system, because I'm capturing its traffic and passing it directly to the network card, without the kernel's knowledge.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense: `/proc/net/tcp` reflects what is happening in the system, it isn't read by the kernel. Furthermore you can't do something without the kernel's knowledge. What are you trying to accomplish? Who's going to read the statistics that you want to fake?

Comment: The statistics in this file are read by utilities such as netstat and ss that are available to users, and this is what I want to achieve. And... of course I can do things without the kernel knowledge, it is called bypassing the kernel.  If you do RDMA than the network card pass data to/from user space program without the kernel knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/proc/net/tcp` is not a real file, that can be edited. Each time you read from it, kernel allocates temporary buffer called a *seq file*, and writes statistics there from **current** in-kernel data.

You may only hjack that by changing code in `tcp4_seq_show()` in `net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c` and subsequent functions.

Note that `/proc/net/tcp` is actually is a symlink to a `/proc/self/net/tcp`, so if you put your process into a namespace, it won't see your connections at all.

Comment: Thanks myaut. Can I achieve that by creating a kernel module instead of changing the kernel code?

Comment: @avner: I think you can do that. I think that the easiest way to do that is to silently remove `/proc/self/net/tcp`, copy-paste related code from `net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c` and change it the way you want to.

Comment: thanks again. Will this allow standard utilities such as netstat and ss to present data of my fake socket among the standard TCP sockets? I mean where will they find the data if I silently remove /proc/self/net/tcp?

Comment: Not only remove, but create a new entry with fake data.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand; however, I still misses something :-(. I see several opions: 1. Chnage just struct seq_file of my fake socket - this would be ideal; however, I don't understand how to do that from a kernel module that is outside the kernel itself. 2. Change the **current** in kernel data regarding my fake socket - this is equivalent to my orig question: how to change a line in /proc/net/tcp? 3. silently remove /proc/self/net/tcp and provide new data in same place - how to do that and when to do that?

Comment: @anver: have you looked at the source code? I.e. http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.18.4/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2306

Comment: thanks. I already looked on that code. My problem was how to fake its output because I don't want to change the kernel code itself. I am only able to add kernel module.  I now think that I have 2 options: 1) to create a netdev module that will be added in the "network chain" of my interface and will change at runtime the internal data and counters of my sockets in the kernel. 2) to write a standard kernel module that will hijack the "show" function you told me and will provide its output with my changes.  Is this what you have meant?

Comment: Hey @avner, were you ever able to find a solution for this? I am also trying something similar. My aim is also to put a fake entry inside /proc/net/tcp

Comment: @nitinsh99 - no.  I believe it requires hijacking the kernel code which doesn't worth my need in this case.  Hence, I represented my user the info from "mynetstat" and not from the system's netstat