# How to find out what function is runnng when reading /proc

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, proc, strace

I am trying to write a kernel module that hides some sockets from netstat. 
I checked how netstat is working and saw that it's reading from `/proc/net/tcp`.

Now I am stuck. I am trying to figure out what is happening when I am reading the `/proc/net/tcp` file. After a little research in Google I found that it's using `tcp4_seq_show` function.

My question is how can I find out which function is used without googling it?

I tried using strace like -

```
strace -y -yy -v cat /proc/net/tcp
```

but the output not contain any reference to the `tcp4_seq_show` function or any another kernel function.

the relevant output -

```
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff5ec3e1580) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff5ec3d6000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55c369b3b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff5ec420000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ff5ec3e2000, 71701)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55c36a40e000
brk(0x55c36a42f000)                     = 0x55c36a42f000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5698896, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 5698896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff5ebc7f000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/tcp", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
mmap(NULL, 139264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff5ebc5d000
read(3, "  sl  local_address rem_address "..., 131072) = 900
write(1, "  sl  local_address rem_address "..., 900  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 00000000:0915 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 69736 1 ffff9f59772fc600 100 0 0 10 0                     
   1: 3500007F:0035 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   102        0 31698 1 ffff9f59772f9a40 100 0 0 10 0                     
   2: 00000000:0016 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 38399 1 ffff9f5972c3a300 100 0 0 10 5                     
   3: 0100007F:0277 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 38548 1 ffff9f5972c3b480 100 0 0 10 0                     
   4: 0100007F:A879 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 44812 1 ffff9f59772fd780 100 0 0 10 0                     
) = 900
read(3, "", 131072)                     = 0
munmap(0x7ff5ebc5d000, 139264)          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Tried also using `ltrace` but it's returning an empty output...

So how can I determinate which function is used without knowing all the kernel and without googling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can trace kernel calls simply with userspace tools. What you are probably looking for is [`ftrace`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt), then you could (if your kernel supports it) do something like this:

```
sysctl kernel.ftrace_enabled=1
echo function_graph > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
cat /proc/net/tcp
echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
less /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace
```

For further information on what exactly goes on when you read `/proc/net/tcp`, you could download the kernel source files and/or read the kernel documentation, eg. about the [virtual filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt),  [/proc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) and the [seq_file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt) interface.

As the `/proc` filesystem is a kernel feature to make system information available to userspace, I don't know if it's possible to hide sockets from `netstat` (cf. [How can I edit /proc/net/tcp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197613/270414)).